# адаптивное видео

Tags: css3, видео

столкулся с проблемой что когда помещаешь video в container 50% то видео ужимаеться, буду признателен за помощь
html:

```
<section>
    <div class="vd__row">
                        <div class="vd__col"> </div>
                        <div class="vd__col">
                            <video controls preload="none" class="vd__video" poster="img/video.svg">
                                <source src="img/video.mp4">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<section>
```

css:

```
.vd__row {display: flex;}
.vd__col {width: 50%;}
.vd__video {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно тег video ещё обернуть наприпер wrapper и position: absolute, если есть постер то для него нужно прописать object-fit: cover; чтобы был на всю ширину и высоту видео

```
css:

    &__video-wrapper {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 56.25%;
            height: 0;
            width: 100%;   
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        &__video {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;  
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover; - чтобы постер был всю ширину и высоту видео
        }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пояснения к вашему ответу